# "Sistema de variáveis" com expressões regulares

Tags: php, string, regex

Tenho um arquivo mais ou menos assim:

```
%usuario: 'Anônimo'
Olá <b>%{usuario}</b>
```

(Esse é só um exemplo e não é o caso real), mas creio que se fosse explicar o problema real daria bem mais trabalho para entender, então é o seguinte: eu sou péssimo em expressões regulares e tenho que exibir esse arquivo substituindo as variáveis que sempre estarão nesse modelo:

```
%var_name = valor;
```

E exibi-las quando forem requisitadas, dessa forma: `%{var_name}`

Comment: Não compreendto qual é o resutado final a que quer chegar. Pode explicar mais na pergunta?

Comment: Se eu declarar uma variável idade com valor de 17, e no arquivo houver 'Eu tenho %{idade} anos de idade' a saída seria 'Eu tenho 17 anos de idade' entendeu? (Eu não posso editar o arquivo por que está fora do meu servidor)

Comment: O que exatamente pode ter em ´valor´? Me parece que vai ter que criar algum tipo de minilinguagem para lidar com strings/números. Um `eval` não seria legal já que o arquivo não está no seu servidor..

Comment: vc está montando um sistema de template?

Comment: Não é por nada, mas regex é a última coisa a se usar num caso desses.

Comment: Sim é mais ou menos um sistema de template. @Bacco eu estava pensando em usar regex para devolver o nome da variável e o valor dela, e usar para substitui-los nos arquivos, mas se você tem um método melhor sinta-se a vontade para compartilha-lo.

Comment: @Júnior postei uma solução bem didática para que fique fácil você aproveitar e adaptar conforme o uso. Regex seria matar pombo com tiro de canhão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solução recomendada sem regex:

O exemplo a seguir faz a mesclagem de dois textos, um com as variáveis e outro com os templates. Creio que fica bem fácil adaptar para seu uso:

```
<?php

   $variaveis = <<<DELIMITADOR
      usuario: chico
      mensagens: 17
DELIMITADOR;

   $texto = <<<DELIMITADOR
      Ola %{usuario}, voce tem %{mensagens} mensagens!
DELIMITADOR;

   $linhas = explode(chr(10), $variaveis); // divite o texto em array, pela quebra de linha
   foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
      $partes = explode(':',$linha);       // divide cada linha em 2 partes, pelos ":"
      $variavel = trim($partes[0]);        // Remove os espaços em branco
      $valor= trim($partes[1]);            // Remove os espaços em branco
      // Agora, basta fazer a troca da %{variavel} pelo valor:
      $texto = str_replace('%{'.$variavel.'}',$valor, $texto);
   }

   echo htmlentities($texto);

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Ola chico, voce tem 17 mensagens!
```

Basta adaptar as declarações das variáveis e do texto pro seu caso, ou simplesmente ler ambos de arquivos externos.

> Mesmo que esteja tudo num arquivo só, basta usar o mesmo princípio do `foreach` e do `explode` para separar o arquivo em várias linhas, e dividir a parte das variáveis da parte do template em si (por exemplo, verificando se a linha inicia com `%`).

Answer (score 3):

Dependendo dos requisitos (já que foi mencionado que a pergunta é um exemplo simplificado), o objetivo de substituir variáveis e gerar conteúdo baseado em um modelo vindo de fora do programa pode ser alcançado com um mecanismo de templates.

## Vantagens

### Não reinventar a roda

É melhor reaproveitar o árduo trabalho de outros desenvolvedores do que implementar algo assim "do zero". Você evita gastar tempo próprio e evita muitos erros e percalços.

### Mais recursos (formatação, listagem, variáveis)

A princípio pode ser que seja necessário apenas substituir um ou dois campos. Mas o que fazer quando a entrada contiver, digamos uma lista de itens? E a formatação de datas?

A vantagem de usar um *template engine* genérico é que ele já vem "de brinde" com esses recursos, e outros.

---

## Desvantagens

### Memória e armazenamento

Usar uma *template engine* provavelmente vai agregar mais arquivos e classes do que uma solução própria mais simples.

### Desempenho

Dependendo dos recursos necessários, uma *template engine* pode ser menos eficiente, já que tem muitos recursos não usados. Entretanto, dependendo da quantidade de operações realizadas de substituição, isso o quadro pode mudar.

---

## Exemplos de *template engines*

### [Blitz](http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/blitz_en.html#basics-variables)

Código de exemplo:

```php
$View = new Blitz();
$View->load('hello {{ BEGIN block }} {{ $name }} {{ END block }}');
$View->block('/block', array('name' => 'Dude'));
$View->display();
```

Produz:

> "hello Dude "

### [phpTenjin](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/phptenjin-users-guide.html)

Template:

```php
Hello {==$name=}!
```

O template é convertido para PHP:

```php
<?php echo 'Hello ', $name, '!'; ?>
```

A execução pode ser feita assim:

```php
require_once 'Tenjin.php';
$engine = new Tenjin_Engine();
$context = array('name'=>'World');
$output = $engine->render('ex.phtml', $context);
echo($output);
```

Saída:

> Hello World!

## [eZ Components - Template](http://www.ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Template#class-overview)

Código para execução:

```php
// Autoload classes ezcomponent 
function __autoload( $className ) {
    ezcBase::autoload( $className );
}

//cria engine com configuração padrão
$t = new ezcTemplate();

//passar variável para o template
$t->send->a = 1;

// compila o template e imprime a saída
echo $t->process( "hello_world.ezt" );
```

Template:

```php
{use $a, $b = 2}
{$a}, {$b}
```

Saída:

> 1, 2

### [Dwoo](https://github.com/emulienfou/dwoo/wiki/Dwoo-for-Developers)

Template:

```php
Hello {$name}
```

Código para execução:

```php
require 'lib/Dwoo/Autoloader.php';
\Dwoo\Autoloader::register();

$dwoo = new \Dwoo\Core();
$data = array('name'=>'World');
$dwoo->output('caminho/template.tpl', $data);
```