# O que é motor de template?

Tags: php, template

A pouco, fiquei sabendo sobre o motor de template em PHP. Por alto, eu entendi o que é, mas tenho dúvidas.

• **É uma "linguagem de programação?"** Coloquei entre aspas pôs li isso em um site:

> Propósito
>
> A princípio, uma linguagem ou motor de templates é usado para, entre
>   outras coisas, agilizar o trabalho de quem vai fazer a parte visual de
>   um projeto Web.

• **O que realmente é um motor de template? Pra que serve? É o que está escrito na citação acima ou é outra coisa?**

• **Pode ser criado em outras linguagens ou só em PHP?**

Poderiam dar exemplos, se possível de como criar um em PHP? Pois não tenho ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Template engine se aplica a qualquer linguagem. Ele utiliza recursos da linguagem logo chamar de linguagem de programção é meio forte o mais adequado seria "uma notação simplificada/melhorada". [Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12661/91) tem um exemplo bem basico de template engine e outras considerações.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não gosto da palavra motor para *engine* neste contexto, prefiro mecanismo.

O PHP já é um mecanismo de gabarito (já que é pra traduzir). Ele pega um texto que em tese é um HTML e permite inserir algumas coisas externas que serão definidas no momento da sua execução.

Por isso é um pouco estranho ter outros mecanismos para uso com PHP. Tá, até entendo que as pessoas queriam algo mais flexível e principalmente com sintaxe mais fácil.

O *template engine* é o software que pega um texto e faz a substituição de partes deste texto por alguma informação a ser definida, seja por um código, seja por um padrão que será determinado por alguma regra fixa.

Em geral eles operam com base em uma convenção de que um determinado caractere ou sequência de caracteres especifica que ali não é um texto e sim é algo que deverá obter um resultado que será inserido no texto.

A forma de operar de cada um é algo que ele define.

É possível que ele carregue uma linguagem de programação nele, mas ele não é a linguagem de programação.

A função deste mecanismo é dar facilidade de escrever um texto da forma mais ou menos natural como uma pessoa faria e permitir a personalização de trechos dele.

A alternativa é ter que programar tudo e usar o texto como literais *string* no código, que não é ruim para um programador, mas pode ser trágico para uma pessoa que tenha outra função, como um *designer* ou mesmo outro usuário mais leigo, até porque esses mecanismo podem ser usados em diversos contextos.

Até no Word da Microsoft ou outros fornecedores possui um mecanismo de gabarito que interpreta o texto e pode preencher as lacunas deixadas no texto, o que curiosamente quase ninguém sabe da existência disto, muitas vezes reinventado a roda em suas aplicações.

Então não é que pode ser usado em outras linguagens, pode ser usado em qualquer coisa que exija que um texto seja gerado com base fixa mas que tenha lacunas a serem preenchidas dinamicamente.

Na verdade nem precisa ser texto, mas ele é bem mais comum e mais simples de realizar.

Para web pode facilitar a criação de páginas por tornar o fluxo mais próximo de como se faria se a página não tivesse conteúdo dinâmico.

Como criar um mecanismo é algo muito amplo, embora um bem simples pode ser feito até com Regex. Basta dizer o padrão que encontrará no texto que é o que deve ser substituído, pegar o conteúdo que está ali dentro, interpretar, no caso mais simples pode ser só um `if`, `switch` ou um *array* associativos* com palavras-chave que devem ser substituídas.

```
$template=file_get_contents('template.php');
$re = "/%(\\w*?)%/"; 
$subst = "<?php $1(); ?>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $template);
file_put_contents('template.php',$result);
```

Exemplo retirado [dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32696143/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Template.php).

Tem [outra pergunta lá com um outro exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18029339/221800).

Comment: Só a primeira frase já vale +1